# Players forget newly trained position

Tags: football-manager-2014

It seems whatever I try, I can't make a player learn a new position and stick with it. According to the guidelines posted elsewhere, I tried to make two young (18-23 y.o.) players with "Accomplished" on some position to learn it to the level of "natural". I did:

- Set individual training for new position
- Play each of the players on this new position (almost exclusively)
- Be sure that they are pleased with their training schedule

However, what happens is that when I see that the level of position familiarity becomes "natural" and remove the individual training for new position, they lapse back into "accomplished" in a matter of weeks. I do play them both in the newly trained positions still, but that doesn't help. All I can do is start training for the new position again which will just take time from their training.

What am I doing wrong? How can I make players not forget the newly trained position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part

> However, what happens is that when I see that the level of position familiarity becomes "natural" and remove the individual training for new position,

is what you're doing wrong. Leave them training in that new position until the option itself disappears. At that stage, they'll have fully learned the new position.